# Android Java file create java.io.FileNotFoundException (File name too long)

Tags: java, android

I have a small Java code in Android Studio. I run it in emulator (Android 7.1.1 API 25).

How I validate a file name and file name length?

Should I check the length with path name or only file name!

I found Android support 255 character as a file name.

File name text in Language Bengali (UNICODE UTF-8)

```java
File downloadFile = new File("/storage/emulated/0/MyDownload/আমার সোনার বাংলা আমি তোমায় ভালোবাসি চিরদিন তোমার আকাশ তোমার বাতাস আমার প্রাণে বাজায় বাঁশি ও মা ফাগুনে তোর.mp4");
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(downloadFile, true);
```

```java
downloadFile.toString().length() // OUTPUT: 142
```

**ERROR:** java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/MyDownload/আমার সোনার বাংলা আমি তোমায় ভালোবাসি চিরদিন তোমার আকাশ তোমার বাতাস আমার প্রাণে বাজায় বাঁশি ও মা ফাগুনে তোর.mp4 (File name too long)

Comment: You do not have access to files in `Downloads/` on Android 11+, unless your app is the one that downloaded it. Please consider using the Storage Access Framework (`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument`) instead.

Comment: it has file access ```File downloadFile = new File("/storage/emulated/0/MyDownload/abcd.mp4");
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(downloadFile, true);``` it works and file write is ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```java
String name = "আমার-সোনার-বাংলা-আমি-তোমায়-ভালোবাসি-চিরদিন-তোমার-আকাশ-তোমার-বাতাস-আমার-প্রাণে-বাজায়-বাঁশি-ও-মা-ফাগুনে-তোর.mp4";
final byte[] utf8Bytes = name.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
if(utf8Bytes.length > 255) {
    name = new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(utf8Bytes, 0, 255), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
System.out.println(name);
```

Comment: It works but it cut the file extension. I will manage it. Thanks anyway @ABHIJIT, at last found a good way. Love you ... ...

Comment: yes, you just split extension name and cut file name to 255 bytes